# Crear archivo CSV web scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy realizando un raspado web a una pagina de sismos, necesito guardar la tabla completa en un archivo CSV, las lineas de codigo que tengo ya realizan el CSV pero no me guarda de manera correcta los datos.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


e = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.sismologia.cl/ultimos_sismos.html").read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(e, 'html.parser')

# Ejemplo de como imprimir todo
# print soup.prettify()

# Obtenemos la tabla

tabla_sismos = soup.find_all('table')[0]

# Obtenemos todas las filas
rows = tabla_sismos.find_all("tr")

for row in rows:
    # obtenemos todas las columns
    cells = row.find_all("td")
    linea = ""
    for cell in cells:
        linea += cell.get_text() + '\t'

with open('Sismos.csv', 'a',newline='') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow(linea)
```

Comment: Es una pregunta?

Comment: Se habia desordenado lo siento, editada

Comment: claramente yo recomendaría pandas para un mejor manejo de los datos :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para empezar `linea` en

```
with open('Sismos.csv', 'a',newline='') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow(linea)
```

Es undefined

Debes crear un array para iterarlo e ir añadiendo cada uno de sus valores al `csv` (`output_rows`), en mi caso he hecho uso de `writerows` que se usa para pasarle el array y la propia librería ya se encarga del resto, también puedes usar `writerow`, pero debes tener en cuenta ésta solo hace 1 `insert`, si quiere añadir cabeceras al CSV puedes hacerlo creando un `array de array de strings` y luego usar `writerows` antes desde `writerows(output_rows)`. Por ejemplo:

```
cabeceras = [
    ["Fecha local",
     "Fecha UTC",
     "LAT",
     "LONG",
     "Profundidad",
     "Magnitud",
     "Ref"]
]

with open('Sismos.csv', 'a', newline="") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=";")
    writer.writerows(cabeceras)
    writer.writerows(output_rows)
```

Claramente no tenemos porqué hacer a mano las cabeceras, éstas ya están en la tabla.

Y este es la solución a tu problema. Saludos :)

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

e = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.sismologia.cl/ultimos_sismos.html").read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(e, 'html.parser')

tabla_sismos = soup.find_all('table')[0]
rows = tabla_sismos.find_all("tr")
output_rows = []
for row in rows:
    # obtenemos todas las columns
    cells = row.find_all("td")
    output_row = []
    if len(cells) > 0:
        for cell in cells:
            output_row.append(cell.text)
        output_rows.append(output_row)

with open('Sismos.csv', 'a', newline="") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=";")
    writer.writerows(output_rows)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, solucione el problema. nose si tu puedes ayudarme, si realizo un nuevo raspado y si hay algun dato duplicado no lo guarde como lo podria realizar?

Comment: Para ello debes primero abrir el CSV, crear un `array` de los datos, y comprobar con los datos que hay en `cell`. Sería algo así `data = list(csv.reader(csvfile))`) tendrás un array de todos lo que hay en el CSV y luego en tu mismo código en la parte de `for cell in cell` hacer una comprobación tal que así `if not cell in miArrayDelCSV:` y listo. Que a lo mejor he ido muy rápido y me he saltado cosas, puede ser, pero es una idea de cómo hacerlo

Comment: Muchas gracias realizare una nueva pregunta a ver si alguien me ayuda.